# How to get POST, DELETE in django request

Tags: python, django

Where does django store the `PUT` and `DELETE` request information. Is this in `POST` or something?

```
if not (request.POST.get(required_arg) or request.GET.get(required_arg) or  request.DELETE.get(required_arg)): 

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'DELETE'
```

Comment: PUT / DELETE are a semantic naming of a POST request. Essentially all requests are either a get or a post. You should be checking for the POST method  here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because most web browsers don't actually support `PUT`, `DELETE`, or `PATCH`, Django (as well as other frameworks) simulates those with a `POST`.

If you don't actually know which method the parameter you want will use you could use `request.REQUEST.get(required_arg)` which checks the `POST` variables first and then `GET`.  The Django docs discourage this in favor of explicitly `request.GET` or `request.POST` for most circumstances.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/

Answer (score 0):

You can get PUT/DELETE request data by using QuerySet.

```py
from django.http import QueryDict

delete_queryset = QueryDict(request.body)
description = delete_queryset.get('description')
```