# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' is not a valid UUID."]

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In an attempt to write object level permissions in Django with the Django Rest Framework, I have bumped into this error (full error log at bottom)

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' is not a valid UUID."]
```

The error comes from a get query, `ship = Ship.objects.get(id=shipID)`. See file:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission
from Ships.models import Ship

import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

class HasObjectLevelPermissions(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == "GET":
            return True
        else:
            logging.debug("not a GET request")
            shipID = request.POST.get('id',None)
            try:
                ship = Ship.objects.get(id=shipID)  # This line is the issue
                return request.user.userprofile.ship.id == ship.id
            except:
                logging.debug("Error in finding ship when checking permissions")
        return False
```

Below is the Ship model where the UUID is declared.

```
class Ship(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    regNum = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, db_index=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    length = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    beam = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    fleet = models.ForeignKey(Fleet)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    def getRegNum(self):
        return self.regNum
```

**Debugging attempts**

1. Changing `ship = Ship.objects.get(id=shipID)` to `ship = Ship.objects.get(id="some string")` makes the validation error disappear.
2. Changing `ship = Ship.objects.get(id=shipID)` to `ship = Ship.objects.get(id="")` makes the validation error disappear. This one is intriguing because an empty string passes the validation.
3. Changing `shipID = request.POST.get('id',None)` to `shipID = request.GET.get('id',None)` makes the validation error disappear.
4. I have logged the uuid being passed in from the POST request and it is indeed a properly formatted uuid (see below)

[image]

5. I have tried deleting the entire Postgres database along with migrations as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473923/django-core-exceptions-validationerror-error).
6. I have run a "SELECT * FROM" on every single table to ensure that no table has an empty uuid
7. I have consulted the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/db/models/fields/) under `class UUIDField(Field):`.
8. Logging the id from POST body.

   `System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
   June 21, 2017 - 00:44:24
   Django version 1.11.1, using settings 'First_REST_API.settings'
   Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
   Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
   DEBUG:CHECKING PERMISSIONS
   DEBUG:not a GET request
   DEBUG:6b25b0be-610a-49f5-ad60-6df9564185a0
   Internal Server Error: /ships
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   '''Same error as below'''`

Essentially I am trying to retrieve a Ship object that matches an id. This type of query has always worked in the past with strings, unsure why the validation error keeps coming up. Any ideas?

**Full error log**

```
Internal Server Error: /ships
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2392, in to_python
    return uuid.UUID(value)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\uuid.py", line 140, in __init__
    raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
ValueError: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\ViaDjango\First_REST_API\Ships\views.py", line 110, in delete
    ship = Ship.objects.get(id=id)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 374, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1103, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 863, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 420, in as_sql
    where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 373, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py", line 79, in as_sql
    sql, params = compiler.compile(child)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 373, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 170, in as_sql
    rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 103, in process_rhs
    return self.get_db_prep_lookup(value, connection)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 196, in get_db_prep_lookup
    [get_db_prep_value(value, connection, prepared=True)]
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2383, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2397, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' is not a valid UUID."]
ERROR:Internal Server Error: /ships
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2392, in to_python
    return uuid.UUID(value)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\uuid.py", line 140, in __init__
    raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
ValueError: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\ViaDjango\First_REST_API\Ships\views.py", line 110, in delete
    ship = Ship.objects.get(id=id)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 374, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1103, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 863, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 420, in as_sql
    where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 373, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py", line 79, in as_sql
    sql, params = compiler.compile(child)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 373, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 170, in as_sql
    rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 103, in process_rhs
    return self.get_db_prep_lookup(value, connection)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 196, in get_db_prep_lookup
    [get_db_prep_value(value, connection, prepared=True)]
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2383, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\VirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2397, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' is not a valid UUID."]
[21/Jun/2017 00:08:53] "DELETE /ships HTTP/1.1" 500 20510
```

**Edit**
The issue was due to a bug in views.py. Thank you to @Sardorbek Imomaliev for pointing that out. `id = request.GET.get('id', '')` should have been `id = request.POST.get('id', '')`. Note that request.POST will contain the DELETE request body. See the comment under this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898475/how-to-get-post-delete-in-django-request) for more. Thank you to everything that helped.

```
class ShipEndpoint(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,HasObjectLevelPermissions)

    ''' get, post not shown'''

    def delete(self, request, format=None):
        id = request.GET.get('id', '')   #GET should have been DELETE
        ship = Ship.objects.get(id=id)
        # ship.fleet.numberOfShips = ship.fleet.numberOfShips - 1
        ship.fleet.save()
        return Response("success")
        # ship.delete()
```

Comment: well the error is because the uuid field is getting blank

Comment: How is it getting blank?

Comment: try to print(shipID) after taking it from the post input and see if the id is displayed in terminal or not

Comment: It is displayed, posted output in the debugging section in the question

Comment: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string, this is the error what it displays in the terminal, that means somehow the id that you are passing to get is getting truncated to blank string,

Comment: Hmm that's interestering. I have moved the log statement immediately before the get query, and the properly formed hexadecimal is logged. Any idea why it is not being caught by the try block?

Comment: how about passing the id as string after changing it, or remove the try block and check

Comment: Same error both ways. 1) tried to convert shipID to string, and pass in the string. 2) deleted try catch block. 3) combined both methods. Same error every time

Comment: that definately means the uuid is not in valid format, try changing it to something simple and also change it in the database and then query once

Comment: Good suggestion, I tried changing the uuid in the POST body. I changed the last digit to purpose make it incorrect, but properly formatted. That query works because the error has changed to `DoesNotExist at /ships
Ship matching query does not exist.`

Comment: Also Django will not allow changing in the database because that would make the uuid "improperly formatted"

Comment: i guess the problem is with the uuid string, as 32 is the max length, and check the length of your uuid

Comment: 32 without hyphens, 36 with hyphens. It doesn't seem to be a problem with GET requests. Only POST.

Comment: do you have any other id in the database which is not in uuid format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to access `request.POST`

```
shipID = request.POST.get('id',None)
```

on `DELETE` request

> [21/Jun/2017 00:08:53] "DELETE /ships HTTP/1.1" 500 20510

You are checking permission on object then why you are not using `has_object_permission`? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples

Also in your traceback it clearly states that issue is your `views.py`

> File "C:\Users\ptao\Desktop\ViaFleet\ViaDjango\First_REST_API\Ships\views.py", line 110, in delete `ship = Ship.objects.get(id=id)`

We need to see your actual view code

Comment: Can you please take a look at my question too? I'm getting this error too, but from another part of the problem. here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74768301/django-strange-error-with-connection-between-view-template-and-url

Answer (score 4):

You write

> I have logged the uuid being passed in from the POST request and it is indeed a properly formatted uuid (see below)

and your uuid image has the required 32 digits.  However, the line quoted in uuid.py throws that exception when the stripped string has other than 32 digits.

So something is wrong with the type of the id.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/:

> UUIDField¶
>
> class UUIDField(**options)[source]¶
>
> A field for storing universally unique identifiers. Uses Python’s UUID class. When used on PostgreSQL, this stores in a uuid datatype, otherwise in a char(32).

The error line is

> ship = Ship.objects.get(id=shipID)

where shipID is a string.  Should your line be

```
get(id=UUID(shipID))
```

?

Comment: Good idea, but no cookie. I tried like so `ship = Ship.objects.get(id=uuid.UUID(shipID))`. Same validation error.

Comment: Ouch.Is it still printing out the correct uuid just before the call to get()?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried editing the uuid (just the last digit) to make it incorrect but properly formatted. Got an `DoesNotExist` error, which means that Django was happy with that format. Thoughts?

Comment: I just checked your model.  Could you try ship = Ship.objects.get(id=uuid.uuid4(shipID))?

Comment: Another good idea, but yet another error `TypeError at /ships
uuid4() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: Re: your comment: interesting.   Was your last digit a zero or a cap-oh?

Comment: zero, here it is `6b25b0be-610a-49f5-ad60-6df9564185a0`

Comment: Could you change it back and try again?  You may have had a space at the end.

Comment: Same thing, made sure to take note of the spaces this time

Comment: Did you try get(pk=shipID)?  That's from the django doc.